# Why is my build hanging / taking a long time to generate my query plan with many unions?

Tags: pyspark, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories, foundry-python-transform

I notice when I run the same code as my example over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68474926/why-do-i-see-repeated-materializations-of-a-dataframe-in-my-build) but with a `union` or `unionByName` or `unionAll` instead of the `join`, my query planning takes *significantly* longer and can result in a driver OOM.

Code included here for reference, with a slight difference to what occurs inside the `for()` loop.

```py
from pyspark.sql import types as T, functions as F, SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

schema = T.StructType([
  T.StructField("col_1", T.IntegerType(), False),
  T.StructField("col_2", T.IntegerType(), False),
  T.StructField("measure_1", T.FloatType(), False),
  T.StructField("measure_2", T.FloatType(), False),
])
data = [
  {"col_1": 1, "col_2": 2, "measure_1": 0.5, "measure_2": 1.5},
  {"col_1": 2, "col_2": 3, "measure_1": 2.5, "measure_2": 3.5}
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

right_schema = T.StructType([
  T.StructField("col_1", T.IntegerType(), False)
])
right_data = [
  {"col_1": 1},
  {"col_1": 1},
  {"col_1": 2},
  {"col_1": 2}
]
right_df = spark.createDataFrame(right_data, right_schema)

df = df.unionByName(df)
df = df.join(right_df, on="col_1")
df.show()

"""
+-----+-----+---------+---------+
|col_1|col_2|measure_1|measure_2|
+-----+-----+---------+---------+
|    1|    2|      0.5|      1.5|
|    1|    2|      0.5|      1.5|
|    1|    2|      0.5|      1.5|
|    1|    2|      0.5|      1.5|
|    2|    3|      2.5|      3.5|
|    2|    3|      2.5|      3.5|
|    2|    3|      2.5|      3.5|
|    2|    3|      2.5|      3.5|
+-----+-----+---------+---------+
"""

df.explain()

"""
== Physical Plan ==
*(6) Project [col_1#1800, col_2#1801, measure_1#1802, measure_2#1803]
+- *(6) SortMergeJoin [col_1#1800], [col_1#1808], Inner
   :- *(3) Sort [col_1#1800 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1800, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#5454]
   :     +- Union
   :        :- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
   :        +- *(2) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
   +- *(5) Sort [col_1#1808 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1808, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#5460]
         +- *(4) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1808]
"""

filter_union_cols = ["col_1", "measure_1", "col_2", "measure_2"]
df = df.withColumn("found_filter", F.lit(None))
for filter_col in filter_union_cols:
  stats = df.filter(F.col(filter_col) < F.lit(1)).drop("found_filter")
  df = df.unionByName(
    stats.select(
      "*",
      F.lit(filter_col).alias("found_filter")
    )
  )

df.show()

"""
+-----+-----+---------+---------+------------+                                  
|col_1|col_2|measure_1|measure_2|found_filter|
+-----+-----+---------+---------+------------+
|    1|    2|      0.5|      1.5|        null|
|    1|    2|      0.5|      1.5|        null|
|    1|    2|      0.5|      1.5|        null|
|    1|    2|      0.5|      1.5|        null|
|    2|    3|      2.5|      3.5|        null|
|    2|    3|      2.5|      3.5|        null|
|    2|    3|      2.5|      3.5|        null|
|    2|    3|      2.5|      3.5|        null|
|    1|    2|      0.5|      1.5|   measure_1|
|    1|    2|      0.5|      1.5|   measure_1|
|    1|    2|      0.5|      1.5|   measure_1|
|    1|    2|      0.5|      1.5|   measure_1|
+-----+-----+---------+---------+------------+
"""

df.explain()

# REALLY long query plan.....

"""
== Physical Plan ==
Union
:- *(6) Project [col_1#1800, col_2#1801, measure_1#1802, measure_2#1803, null AS found_filter#1855]
:  +- *(6) SortMergeJoin [col_1#1800], [col_1#1808], Inner
:     :- *(3) Sort [col_1#1800 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:     :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1800, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7637]
:     :     +- Union
:     :        :- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     :        +- *(2) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     +- *(5) Sort [col_1#1808 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:        +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1808, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7643]
:           +- *(4) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1808]
:- *(12) Project [col_1#1800, col_2#1801, measure_1#1802, measure_2#1803, col_1 AS found_filter#1860]
:  +- *(12) SortMergeJoin [col_1#1800], [col_1#1808], Inner
:     :- *(9) Sort [col_1#1800 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:     :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1800, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7654]
:     :     +- Union
:     :        :- *(7) Filter (col_1#1800 < 1)
:     :        :  +- *(7) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     :        +- *(8) Filter (col_1#1800 < 1)
:     :           +- *(8) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     +- *(11) Sort [col_1#1808 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:        +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1808, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7660]
:           +- *(10) Filter (col_1#1808 < 1)
:              +- *(10) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1808]
:- *(18) Project [col_1#1800, col_2#1801, measure_1#1802, measure_2#1803, measure_1 AS found_filter#1880]
:  +- *(18) SortMergeJoin [col_1#1800], [col_1#1808], Inner
:     :- *(15) Sort [col_1#1800 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:     :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1800, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7671]
:     :     +- Union
:     :        :- *(13) Filter (measure_1#1802 < 1.0)
:     :        :  +- *(13) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     :        +- *(14) Filter (measure_1#1802 < 1.0)
:     :           +- *(14) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     +- *(17) Sort [col_1#1808 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:        +- ReusedExchange [col_1#1808], Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1808, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7643]
:- *(24) Project [col_1#1800, col_2#1801, measure_1#1802, measure_2#1803, measure_1 AS found_filter#2022]
:  +- *(24) SortMergeJoin [col_1#1800], [col_1#1808], Inner
:     :- *(21) Sort [col_1#1800 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:     :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1800, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7688]
:     :     +- Union
:     :        :- *(19) Filter ((col_1#1800 < 1) AND (measure_1#1802 < 1.0))
:     :        :  +- *(19) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     :        +- *(20) Filter ((col_1#1800 < 1) AND (measure_1#1802 < 1.0))
:     :           +- *(20) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     +- *(23) Sort [col_1#1808 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:        +- ReusedExchange [col_1#1808], Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1808, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7660]
:- *(30) Project [col_1#1800, col_2#1801, measure_1#1802, measure_2#1803, col_2 AS found_filter#1900]
:  +- *(30) SortMergeJoin [col_1#1800], [col_1#1808], Inner
:     :- *(27) Sort [col_1#1800 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:     :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1800, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7705]
:     :     +- Union
:     :        :- *(25) Filter (col_2#1801 < 1)
:     :        :  +- *(25) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     :        +- *(26) Filter (col_2#1801 < 1)
:     :           +- *(26) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     +- *(29) Sort [col_1#1808 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:        +- ReusedExchange [col_1#1808], Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1808, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7643]
:- *(36) Project [col_1#1800, col_2#1801, measure_1#1802, measure_2#1803, col_2 AS found_filter#2023]
:  +- *(36) SortMergeJoin [col_1#1800], [col_1#1808], Inner
:     :- *(33) Sort [col_1#1800 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:     :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1800, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7722]
:     :     +- Union
:     :        :- *(31) Filter ((col_1#1800 < 1) AND (col_2#1801 < 1))
:     :        :  +- *(31) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     :        +- *(32) Filter ((col_1#1800 < 1) AND (col_2#1801 < 1))
:     :           +- *(32) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     +- *(35) Sort [col_1#1808 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:        +- ReusedExchange [col_1#1808], Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1808, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7660]
:- *(42) Project [col_1#1800, col_2#1801, measure_1#1802, measure_2#1803, col_2 AS found_filter#2024]
:  +- *(42) SortMergeJoin [col_1#1800], [col_1#1808], Inner
:     :- *(39) Sort [col_1#1800 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:     :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1800, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7739]
:     :     +- Union
:     :        :- *(37) Filter ((measure_1#1802 < 1.0) AND (col_2#1801 < 1))
:     :        :  +- *(37) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     :        +- *(38) Filter ((measure_1#1802 < 1.0) AND (col_2#1801 < 1))
:     :           +- *(38) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     +- *(41) Sort [col_1#1808 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:        +- ReusedExchange [col_1#1808], Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1808, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7643]
:- *(48) Project [col_1#1800, col_2#1801, measure_1#1802, measure_2#1803, col_2 AS found_filter#2028]
:  +- *(48) SortMergeJoin [col_1#1800], [col_1#1808], Inner
:     :- *(45) Sort [col_1#1800 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:     :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1800, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7756]
:     :     +- Union
:     :        :- *(43) Filter (((col_1#1800 < 1) AND (measure_1#1802 < 1.0)) AND (col_2#1801 < 1))
:     :        :  +- *(43) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     :        +- *(44) Filter (((col_1#1800 < 1) AND (measure_1#1802 < 1.0)) AND (col_2#1801 < 1))
:     :           +- *(44) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     +- *(47) Sort [col_1#1808 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:        +- ReusedExchange [col_1#1808], Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1808, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7660]
:- *(54) Project [col_1#1800, col_2#1801, measure_1#1802, measure_2#1803, measure_2 AS found_filter#1920]
:  +- *(54) SortMergeJoin [col_1#1800], [col_1#1808], Inner
:     :- *(51) Sort [col_1#1800 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:     :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1800, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7773]
:     :     +- Union
:     :        :- *(49) Filter (measure_2#1803 < 1.0)
:     :        :  +- *(49) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     :        +- *(50) Filter (measure_2#1803 < 1.0)
:     :           +- *(50) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     +- *(53) Sort [col_1#1808 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:        +- ReusedExchange [col_1#1808], Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1808, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7643]
:- *(60) Project [col_1#1800, col_2#1801, measure_1#1802, measure_2#1803, measure_2 AS found_filter#2025]
:  +- *(60) SortMergeJoin [col_1#1800], [col_1#1808], Inner
:     :- *(57) Sort [col_1#1800 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:     :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1800, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7790]
:     :     +- Union
:     :        :- *(55) Filter ((col_1#1800 < 1) AND (measure_2#1803 < 1.0))
:     :        :  +- *(55) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     :        +- *(56) Filter ((col_1#1800 < 1) AND (measure_2#1803 < 1.0))
:     :           +- *(56) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     +- *(59) Sort [col_1#1808 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:        +- ReusedExchange [col_1#1808], Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1808, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7660]
:- *(66) Project [col_1#1800, col_2#1801, measure_1#1802, measure_2#1803, measure_2 AS found_filter#2026]
:  +- *(66) SortMergeJoin [col_1#1800], [col_1#1808], Inner
:     :- *(63) Sort [col_1#1800 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:     :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1800, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7807]
:     :     +- Union
:     :        :- *(61) Filter ((measure_1#1802 < 1.0) AND (measure_2#1803 < 1.0))
:     :        :  +- *(61) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     :        +- *(62) Filter ((measure_1#1802 < 1.0) AND (measure_2#1803 < 1.0))
:     :           +- *(62) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     +- *(65) Sort [col_1#1808 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:        +- ReusedExchange [col_1#1808], Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1808, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7643]
:- *(72) Project [col_1#1800, col_2#1801, measure_1#1802, measure_2#1803, measure_2 AS found_filter#2029]
:  +- *(72) SortMergeJoin [col_1#1800], [col_1#1808], Inner
:     :- *(69) Sort [col_1#1800 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:     :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1800, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7824]
:     :     +- Union
:     :        :- *(67) Filter (((col_1#1800 < 1) AND (measure_1#1802 < 1.0)) AND (measure_2#1803 < 1.0))
:     :        :  +- *(67) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     :        +- *(68) Filter (((col_1#1800 < 1) AND (measure_1#1802 < 1.0)) AND (measure_2#1803 < 1.0))
:     :           +- *(68) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     +- *(71) Sort [col_1#1808 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:        +- ReusedExchange [col_1#1808], Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1808, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7660]
:- *(78) Project [col_1#1800, col_2#1801, measure_1#1802, measure_2#1803, measure_2 AS found_filter#2027]
:  +- *(78) SortMergeJoin [col_1#1800], [col_1#1808], Inner
:     :- *(75) Sort [col_1#1800 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:     :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1800, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7841]
:     :     +- Union
:     :        :- *(73) Filter ((col_2#1801 < 1) AND (measure_2#1803 < 1.0))
:     :        :  +- *(73) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     :        +- *(74) Filter ((col_2#1801 < 1) AND (measure_2#1803 < 1.0))
:     :           +- *(74) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     +- *(77) Sort [col_1#1808 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:        +- ReusedExchange [col_1#1808], Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1808, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7643]
:- *(84) Project [col_1#1800, col_2#1801, measure_1#1802, measure_2#1803, measure_2 AS found_filter#2030]
:  +- *(84) SortMergeJoin [col_1#1800], [col_1#1808], Inner
:     :- *(81) Sort [col_1#1800 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:     :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1800, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7858]
:     :     +- Union
:     :        :- *(79) Filter (((col_1#1800 < 1) AND (col_2#1801 < 1)) AND (measure_2#1803 < 1.0))
:     :        :  +- *(79) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     :        +- *(80) Filter (((col_1#1800 < 1) AND (col_2#1801 < 1)) AND (measure_2#1803 < 1.0))
:     :           +- *(80) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     +- *(83) Sort [col_1#1808 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:        +- ReusedExchange [col_1#1808], Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1808, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7660]
:- *(90) Project [col_1#1800, col_2#1801, measure_1#1802, measure_2#1803, measure_2 AS found_filter#2031]
:  +- *(90) SortMergeJoin [col_1#1800], [col_1#1808], Inner
:     :- *(87) Sort [col_1#1800 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:     :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1800, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7875]
:     :     +- Union
:     :        :- *(85) Filter (((measure_1#1802 < 1.0) AND (col_2#1801 < 1)) AND (measure_2#1803 < 1.0))
:     :        :  +- *(85) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     :        +- *(86) Filter (((measure_1#1802 < 1.0) AND (col_2#1801 < 1)) AND (measure_2#1803 < 1.0))
:     :           +- *(86) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
:     +- *(89) Sort [col_1#1808 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:        +- ReusedExchange [col_1#1808], Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1808, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7643]
+- *(96) Project [col_1#1800, col_2#1801, measure_1#1802, measure_2#1803, measure_2 AS found_filter#2032]
   +- *(96) SortMergeJoin [col_1#1800], [col_1#1808], Inner
      :- *(93) Sort [col_1#1800 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1800, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7892]
      :     +- Union
      :        :- *(91) Filter ((((col_1#1800 < 1) AND (measure_1#1802 < 1.0)) AND (col_2#1801 < 1)) AND (measure_2#1803 < 1.0))
      :        :  +- *(91) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
      :        +- *(92) Filter ((((col_1#1800 < 1) AND (measure_1#1802 < 1.0)) AND (col_2#1801 < 1)) AND (measure_2#1803 < 1.0))
      :           +- *(92) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
      +- *(95) Sort [col_1#1808 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
         +- ReusedExchange [col_1#1808], Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1808, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#7660]
"""
```

I'm seeing a significantly longer query plan here, and especially as the number of iterations of the `for()` loop increases, the performance degrades terribly.

How can I improve my performance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known limitation of iterative algorithms in Spark.  At the moment, every iteration of the loop causes the inner nodes to be re-evaluated and stacked upon the outer `df` variable.

This means your query planning process is taking `O(exp(n))` where n is the number of iterations of your loop.

There's a tool in Palantir Foundry called Transforms Verbs that can help with this.

Simply import `transforms.verbs.dataframes.union_many` and call it upon the total set of dataframes you wish to materialize (assuming your logic will allow for it, i.e. one iteration of the loop doesn't depend upon the result of a prior iteration of the loop.

The code above should instead be modified to:

```py
from pyspark.sql import types as T, functions as F, SparkSession
from transforms.verbs.dataframes import union_many

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

schema = T.StructType([
  T.StructField("col_1", T.IntegerType(), False),
  T.StructField("col_2", T.IntegerType(), False),
  T.StructField("measure_1", T.FloatType(), False),
  T.StructField("measure_2", T.FloatType(), False),
])
data = [
  {"col_1": 1, "col_2": 2, "measure_1": 0.5, "measure_2": 1.5},
  {"col_1": 2, "col_2": 3, "measure_1": 2.5, "measure_2": 3.5}
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

right_schema = T.StructType([
  T.StructField("col_1", T.IntegerType(), False)
])
right_data = [
  {"col_1": 1},
  {"col_1": 1},
  {"col_1": 2},
  {"col_1": 2}
]
right_df = spark.createDataFrame(right_data, right_schema)

df = df.unionByName(df)
df = df.join(right_df, on="col_1")
df.show()

"""
+-----+-----+---------+---------+
|col_1|col_2|measure_1|measure_2|
+-----+-----+---------+---------+
|    1|    2|      0.5|      1.5|
|    1|    2|      0.5|      1.5|
|    1|    2|      0.5|      1.5|
|    1|    2|      0.5|      1.5|
|    2|    3|      2.5|      3.5|
|    2|    3|      2.5|      3.5|
|    2|    3|      2.5|      3.5|
|    2|    3|      2.5|      3.5|
+-----+-----+---------+---------+
"""

df.explain()

"""
== Physical Plan ==
*(6) Project [col_1#1800, col_2#1801, measure_1#1802, measure_2#1803]
+- *(6) SortMergeJoin [col_1#1800], [col_1#1808], Inner
   :- *(3) Sort [col_1#1800 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1800, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#5454]
   :     +- Union
   :        :- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
   :        +- *(2) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1800,col_2#1801,measure_1#1802,measure_2#1803]
   +- *(5) Sort [col_1#1808 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_1#1808, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#5460]
         +- *(4) Scan ExistingRDD[col_1#1808]
"""

filter_union_cols = ["col_1", "measure_1", "col_2", "measure_2"]
df = df.withColumn("found_filter", F.lit(None))
union_dfs = []
for filter_col in filter_union_cols:
  stats = df.filter(F.col(filter_col) < F.lit(1)).drop("found_filter")
  union_df = stats.select(
    "*",
    F.lit(filter_col).alias("found_filter")
  )
  union_dfs += [union_df]

df = df.unionByName(
  union_many(union_dfs)
)
```

This will optimize your unions and take significantly less time.

The bottom line: **beware of using any `union` calls inside for/while loops.  If you must use this behavior, use the `transforms.verbs.dataframes.union_many` verb to optimize your final set of DataFrames**

Check out your platform documentation for more information and more helpful Verbs.

**Protip:  Use the included optimization over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68474926/why-do-i-see-repeated-materializations-of-a-dataframe-in-my-build) to further increase your performance**

Comment: How is `union_many()` implemented to avoid this problem?

Comment: I'm also not sure how it avoids the problem. Looking at the source code of `union_many` I see a few checks/ verifications and then there is `unionByName` inside a `while` loop running until only one df is left.

Answer (score 2):

If you receive an error about lists not having an unionByName/union_many attribute, while trying to implement op's solution, try to unpack the union_dfs in the last row with an asterisk prefix, like so:

```
df = df.unionByName(
    union_many(*union_dfs)
)
```

Apparently, Foundry does not unpack the list of dataframe references on its own.