# PySpark Serialized Results too Large OOM for loop in Spark

Tags: pyspark, out-of-memory, palantir-foundry, foundry-python-transform

I have serious difficulties in understanding why I cannot run a transform which, after waiting so many minutes (sometimes hours), returns the error "Serialized Results too large".

In the transform I have a list of dates that I am iterating in a for loop to proceed with delta calculations within specific time intervals.

**The expected dataset is the union of the iterated datasets and should contain 450k rows, not too many, but i have a lot of computing stages, tasks and attempts!!**

*The profile is already set a Medium profile and i can't scale on other profile and i can't set  maxResultSize = 0.*

Example of code:

```
Date_list = [All weeks from: '2021-01-01', to: '2022-01-01'] --> ~50 elements
df_total = spark.createDataframe([], schema)
df_date = []

for date in Date_list:
     tmp = df.filter(between [date,  date-7days]).withColumn('example', F.lit(date))
     
     ........

     df2 = df.join(tmp, 'column', 'inner').......

     df_date += [df2]
df_total = df_total.unionByName(union_many(*df_date))

return df_total
```

Don't pay attention to the syntax. This is just an example to show that there are a series of operations inside the loop. **My desidered output is an dataframe which contains the dataframe of each iteration!**

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

### Initial Theory

You are hitting a known limitation of Spark, similar to the findings discussed over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68807177/why-is-my-build-hanging-taking-a-long-time-to-generate-my-query-plan-with-many).

However, there are ways to work around this by re-thinking your implementation to instead be a series of dispatched instructions describing the batches of data you wish to operate on, similar to how you create your `tmp` DataFrame.

This may unfortunately require quite a bit more work to re-think your logic in this way since you'll want to imagine your manipulations purely as a series of column manipulation commands given to PySpark instead of row-by-row manipulations.  There are some operations you cannot do purely using PySpark calls, so this isn't always possible.  In general it's worth thinking through very carefully.

### Concretely

As an example, your data range calculations are possible to perform purely in PySpark and will be substantially faster if you do this operations over many years or other increased scale. Instead of using Python list comprehension or other logic, we instead use column manipulations on a small set of initial data to build up our ranges.

I've written up some example code here on how you can create your date batches, this should let you perform a `join` to create your `tmp` DataFrame, after which you can describe the types of operations you wish to do to it.

Code to create date ranges (start and end dates of each week of the year):

```py
from pyspark.sql import types as T, functions as F, SparkSession, Window
from datetime import date

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

year_marker_schema = T.StructType([
  T.StructField("max_year", T.IntegerType(), False),
])
year_marker_data = [
    {"max_year": 2022}
]
year_marker_df = spark.createDataFrame(year_marker_data, year_marker_schema)
year_marker_df.show()

"""
+--------+
|max_year|
+--------+
|    2022|
+--------+
"""

previous_week_window = Window.partitionBy(F.col("start_year")).orderBy("start_week_index")

year_marker_df = year_marker_df.select(
    (F.col("max_year") - 1).alias("start_year"),
    "*"
).select(
    F.to_date(F.col("max_year").cast(T.StringType()), "yyyy").alias("max_year_date"),
    F.to_date(F.col("start_year").cast(T.StringType()), "yyyy").alias("start_year_date"),
    "*"
).select(
    F.datediff(F.col("max_year_date"), F.col("start_year_date")).alias("days_between"),
    "*"
).select(
    F.floor(F.col("days_between") / 7).alias("weeks_between"),
    "*"
).select(
    F.sequence(F.lit(0), F.col("weeks_between")).alias("week_indices"),
    "*"
).select(
    F.explode(F.col("week_indices")).alias("start_week_index"),
    "*"
).select(
    F.lead(F.col("start_week_index"), 1).over(previous_week_window).alias("end_week_index"),
    "*"
).select(
    ((F.col("start_week_index") * 7) + 1).alias("start_day"),
    ((F.col("end_week_index") * 7) + 1).alias("end_day"),
    "*"
).select(
    F.concat_ws(
        "-",
        F.col("start_year"),
        F.col("start_day").cast(T.StringType())
    ).alias("start_day_string"),
    F.concat_ws(
        "-",
        F.col("start_year"),
        F.col("end_day").cast(T.StringType())
    ).alias("end_day_string"),
    "*"
).select(
    F.to_date(
        F.col("start_day_string"),
        "yyyy-D"
    ).alias("start_date"),
    F.to_date(
        F.col("end_day_string"),
        "yyyy-D"
    ).alias("end_date"),
    "*"
)

year_marker_df.drop(
    "max_year",
    "start_year",
    "weeks_between",
    "days_between",
    "week_indices",
    "max_year_date",
    "start_day_string",
    "end_day_string",
    "start_day",
    "end_day",
    "start_week_index",
    "end_week_index",
    "start_year_date"
).show()

"""
+----------+----------+
|start_date|  end_date|
+----------+----------+
|2021-01-01|2021-01-08|
|2021-01-08|2021-01-15|
|2021-01-15|2021-01-22|
|2021-01-22|2021-01-29|
|2021-01-29|2021-02-05|
|2021-02-05|2021-02-12|
|2021-02-12|2021-02-19|
|2021-02-19|2021-02-26|
|2021-02-26|2021-03-05|
|2021-03-05|2021-03-12|
|2021-03-12|2021-03-19|
|2021-03-19|2021-03-26|
|2021-03-26|2021-04-02|
|2021-04-02|2021-04-09|
|2021-04-09|2021-04-16|
|2021-04-16|2021-04-23|
|2021-04-23|2021-04-30|
|2021-04-30|2021-05-07|
|2021-05-07|2021-05-14|
|2021-05-14|2021-05-21|
+----------+----------+
only showing top 20 rows
"""
```

### Potential Optimizations

Once you have this code and **if** you are unable to express your work through joins / column derivations alone and are forced to perform the operation with the `union_many`, you may consider using Spark's [localCheckpoint](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.localCheckpoint.html) feature on your `df2` result.  This will allow Spark to simply calculate the resultant DataFrame and not add its query plan onto the result you will push to your `df_total`.  This could be paired with the [cache](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.cache.html) to also keep the resultant DataFrame in memory, but this will depend on your data scale.

`localCheckpoint` and `cache` are useful to avoid re-computing the same DataFrames many times over and truncating the amount of query planning done on top of your intermediate DataFrames.

You'll likely find `localCheckpoint` and `cache` can be useful on your `df` DataFrame as well since it will be used many times over in your loop (assuming you are unable to re-work your logic to use SQL-based operations and instead are still forced to use the loop).

As a quick and dirty summary of when to use each:

**Use `localCheckpoint` on a DataFrame that was complex to compute and is going to be used in operations later.  Oftentimes these are the nodes feeding into `union`s**

**Use `cache` on a DataFrame that is going to be used many times later.  This often is a DataFrame sitting outside of a for/while loop that will be called in the loop**

### All Together

Your initial code

```py
Date_list = [All weeks from: '2021-01-01', to: '2022-01-01'] --> ~50 elements
df_total = spark.createDataframe([], schema)
df_date = []

for date in Date_list:
     tmp = df.filter(between [date,  date-7days]).withColumn('example', F.lit(date))
     
     ........

     df2 = df.join(tmp, 'column', 'inner').......

     df_date += [df2]
df_total = df_total.unionByName(union_many(*df_date))

return df_total
```

Should now look like:

```py
# year_marker_df as derived in my code above

year_marker_df = year_marker_df.cache()

df = df.join(year_marker_df, df.my_date_column between year_marker_df.start_date, year_marker_df.end_date)
# Other work previously in your for_loop, resulting in df_total
return df_total
```

Or, if you are unable to re-work your inner loop operations, you can do some optimizations like:

```py
Date_list = [All weeks from: '2021-01-01', to: '2022-01-01'] --> ~50 elements
df_total = spark.createDataframe([], schema)
df_date = []

df = df.cache()
for date in Date_list:
     tmp = df.filter(between [date,  date-7days]).withColumn('example', F.lit(date))
     
     ........

     df2 = df.join(tmp, 'column', 'inner').......

     df2 = df2.localCheckpoint()
     df_date += [df2]

df_total = df_total.unionByName(union_many(*df_date))

return df_total
```

Comment: I am extremely happy!! I solved the problem using cache () and localCheckpoint!!! Thank you so much for your wonderful explanation! 

As soon as I have time I will implement and also try the first solution! Just one more courtesy: Could you please explain to me why cache and localCheckpoint should be placed right in those spots of code? I can use them also into for loop?! Where? This doesn't change the content of my dataframe in any way right? Thanks again!!!